# Let $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(2)$ independent random variables. Let $Z = \max(X, Y)$. Calculate expected value of $Z$.

Tags: probability

Here a question:

> Let $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(1)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(2)$ be independent random variables. Let $Z = \max(X, Y)$. Calculate expected value of $Z$.

My try:

\begin{align}
P(Z \le z) & = P(\max(X, Y) \le z) = 1 - P(\max(X, Y) > z) \\[10pt]
& = 1-P(X > z)P(Y > z) =  1 - (e^{-z} \cdot e^{-2z}) = 1 - e^{-3z}.
\end{align}

> find distribution function: $F_z = \frac{d}{dz} \space 1 - e^{-3z} = 3e^{-3z}. $
>
> Find expected value: $\int_0^\infty z\cdot F_z \,dz = 3\int_0^\infty z\cdot e^{-3z}\,dz = \frac{1}{3}$.

Right solution is $\frac{7}{6}$. Whats wrong in my way?

Comment: How are you getting $P(Max(X,Y)>z)=P(X>z)P(Y>z)$?

Comment: If the maxiumum of two variables is less than a constant, both variables are.  If the maximum of two variable is greater than a constant at least one variable is.$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq z)=P(X\leq z\cap Y\leq z)\\P(\max(X,Y)> z)=P(X>z\color{red}{\cup} Y>z)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\Pr(Z\le z)=\Pr((X\le z)\cap (Y\le z))=(1-e^{-z})(1-e^{-2z})$ (for $z\gt 0$.) Differentiate to find the density, and then calculate the expectation as usual.

Comment: Why is the first factor $(1 - e^z)$, got $e^z$ and not $e^{-z}$?

Comment: It is a missing minus sign. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: OK, great, seems to work. my bad was @Graham Kemp comment.

Answer (score 2):

If the maxiumum of two variables is less than( or equal to) a constant, then both variables are.

If the maximum of two variable is greater than a constant, then *at least* one variable is.$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq z)=P(X\leq z\cap Y\leq z)\\P(\max(X,Y)> z)=P(X>z\color{red}{\cup} Y>z)$$

Use the former.

Answer (score 1):

You need
$P(Z \le z) = P(\max(X, Y) \le z) = P(X \le z)(Y \le z) = \cdots.$

*Addendum:* With a little thought one can find the *mean* of the max of two exponentials of equal rate $\lambda$ without finding the *distribution.* The minimum is exponential with rate $2\lambda,$
and thus mean $1/2\lambda.$ Then (invoking the no-memory property
of exponential distributions) the additional wait for the max is
exponential with rate $\lambda$ and mean $1/\lambda.$ Thus the
expectation of the max is $1/2\lambda + 1/\lambda = 3/2\lambda.$
This method can be easily extended to find the expectation of
the max of several independent exponentials with a homogeneous rate.

With a little extra though one can find the expectation of the max
of two exponentials $X$ and $Y$ with different rates, say $\lambda$ and $\mu,$ respectively.
The rate of the min is $\nu = \lambda + \mu$ and so its mean is
$1/\nu.$ To finish the wait, you need to know which exponential
waiting time came first. This is $X$ with probability $\lambda/\nu$ and $Y$ with probability $\mu/\nu.$ Then the expected wait from the min to the max is $(1/\mu)(\lambda/\nu) + (1/\lambda)(\mu/\nu).$
Then the total expected wait for the max is
$$(1 + \lambda/\mu + \mu/\lambda)/\nu.$$
For $\lambda = \mu$ it is easy to see that this is the same result
as above for two equal rates.

The brief bit of R code below simulates your problem and illustrates this approach for
$\lambda = 1$ and $\mu = 2.$ (With a million cases, simulated results are accurate to about three places.)

```
 m = 10^6;  mu = 1;  lam = 2
 x = rexp(m,mu); y = rexp(m,lam)
 v = pmin(x,y);  w = pmax(x,y)
 mean(x == v)
 ## 0.333699      # approx. P(X first) = 1/3
 nu = mu + lam;  (1 + lam/mu + mu/lam)/nu
 ## 1.166667      # exact E(max)
 mean(w)
 1.166280         # approx. E(max)
```

Comment: With a rush to give six Answers within about 15 minutes last night, the net effect was to work the problem, not just to answer your question about the approach. Attempting to improve the chance of an actual learning experience, I've written an Addendum to my answer that may give you some additional perspective on this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are exponential random variables with parameters
$1$ and $2$ respectively, and so 
$$E[X] = 1,~ E[Y] = \frac 12.$$

$\min(X,Y)$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $3$ (cf. Gregory Grant's comment that $P\{\min(X,Y) > z\} = P\{X > z\}P\{Y > z\}$
and in your own calculations shown in your question, you found
that $P\{X > z\}P\{Y > z\} = e^{-z}\cdot e^{-2z} = e^{-3z}$.)  So, $$E[\min(X,Y)] = \frac 13.$$
 Now note that $\max(X,Y) + \min(X,Y) = X+Y$ and so
$$E[\max(X,Y)] = E[X] + E[Y] - E[\min(X,Y)
= 1 + \frac 12 - \frac 13 = \frac 76.$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(\min(X,Y)>z)=P(X>z)P(Y>z)$.  Not the max.

Answer (score 0):

Your line $P(Z\le z)=1-P(X>z)P(Y>z)$ is wrong. It excludes cases like $X=z-1, Y=z+1$. Some further thought however will show that $P(Z\le z)=P(X\le z)P(Y\le z)$ covers all the cases and will give you the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x,y) = 2 e^{-x} e^{-2y}.$  Then 
$$
P(\max(X,Y))= \int^\infty_0 \int^x_0 x \,g(x,y) \ dy \ dx +  \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_x y \, g(x,y) \ dy \ dx =\frac{8}{9} + \frac{5}{18}  = \frac{7}{6}.
$$